# Retrieve action layout from ActionBar, inside fragment

Tags: android

How do I retrieve a action layout for an item inside the ActionBar, from 
a Fragment. I have tried to access the layout directly via getActivity().findViewById, 
and via getActivity().findViewById(MenuItem).findViewById(ActionLayout).

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    MenuItem commentMenuItem = (MenuItem) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.menu_item_comment);
    View actionView = commentMenuItem.getActionView();
    TextView commentTextView = (TextView) 
            actionView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_comment_item_textview);

    commentTextView.setText(article.getArticle_comment_count());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `getActionView()` on the `MenuItem` corresponding to that action layout. You get the `MenuItem` from `findItem()`  on the `Menu`, which you get in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.